# View not getting updated

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a simple UI with angular JS, but cant seem to figure out why the view is not getting updated after a controller rpc finishes.

```
<!-- search result view -->
<p>size is {{resultCount}}</p>

<!-- main view which has ng-view -->
<html ng-app="exApp">
    <body ng-controller="exApp.MainCtrl">
        <!-- form which submits to SearchCtrl -->
        <form name="searchform" ng-controller="exApp.SearchCtrl" ng-submit="search()">
            <input type="text" ng-model="queryString">
        </form>
        <div class="view-panel" ng-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
exApp.MainCtrl = function ($scope) {
    $scope.queryString = '';
    $scope.resultCount = 0;
}

exApp.SearchCtrl = function ($scope, $http) {
    function display(response) {
        $scope.poreqs = response["resource"];
        // should update the html, but does not
        $scope.resultCount = $scope.poreqs.length;
    }
    $scope.search = function () {
        $http.get('/search?q=' + $scope.queryString).success(display);
    };
};
```

Comment: If `exApp` is an AngularJS module, then you should use `ng-controller="MainCtrl"` because you already specified the module using `ng-app`. Does that fix it?

Comment: No making it MainCtrl does not work. The Ctrl is getting called, the rpc is sent out and the results come back to the ctrl, just that the view is not getting updated. I am guessing something do with scope.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see it now. You defined `resultCount` on the parent scope (`MainCtrl`) and are setting it on the child scope. Because AngularJS scopes use [prototypical inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/The-Nuances-of-Scope-Prototypal-Inheritance), primitives (like numbers, strings, and booleans) are overwritten when set in a child scope. Model properties should typically have a `.` in them to prevent against this. Change the line to this and it should work: `$scope.$parent.resultCount = $scope.poreqs.length`. Note that this is *not* necessarily the best solution.

Comment: Cool, this works, thanks. What would be a more elegant/natural design/solution in my case, where I have a MainView with a searchbox and SearchView which should display the search results.

Comment: Depends on your specific use case and why you felt you needed a second controller in the first place.

Comment: But feel free to post a new question with some specifics and we can help you out for sure.